# Schedule task can't perform update data on database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, quartz-scheduler

I'm trying to perform a schedule of tasks with `Quartz` NuGet packages. The scheduler works as expected but the problem with my class. The schedule job worked fine while I tried to send SMS With HTTP Header (I'm using an API SMS sender service) but while I tried to perform anything with the database nothing worked as expected. Bellow, I'm sharing my codes.

PaymentIncrease.cs

```
using AmitSMS.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Quartz;

namespace AmitSMS.Data.Services;

public class PaymentIncrease : IJob
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public PaymentIncrease(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        var task = Task.Run(() => Increase());
        return task;
    }

    public void Increase()
    {
        var students = _context.Set<Student>().AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.Status == 1 && (x.Batch1 == 1 || x.Batch2 == 1)).ToList();

        foreach (var student in students)
        {
            Due due = new()
            {
                StudentId = student.StudentId,
                Recurring = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM, yyyy"),
                Amount = 800 * (student.Physics + student.HigherMath),
                PreviousAmount = student.Due
            };

            student.Payment += due.Amount;
            student.Due += due.Amount;

            _context.Update(student);
            _context.Add(due);
        }

        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

SchedulerTask.cs

```
using Quartz;
using Quartz.Impl;

namespace AmitSMS.Data.Services;

public class SchedulerTask
{
    private static readonly string ScheduleSMSExpression = "0 * * ? * *";
    public static async Task StartAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            var scheduler = await StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
            if (!scheduler.IsStarted)
            {
                await scheduler.Start();
            }

            

            // Increase Payment
            var job1 = JobBuilder.Create<PaymentIncrease>().WithIdentity("ExecuteTaskServiceCallJob1", "group1").Build();

            var trigger1 = TriggerBuilder.Create().WithIdentity("ExecuteTaskServiceCallTrigger1", "group1").WithCronSchedule(ScheduleSMSExpression).Build();

       
            //Schedule Payment Job
            await scheduler.ScheduleJob(job1, trigger1);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            
        }
    }
}
```

and on Program.cs did this on the configuration area.

```
SchedulerTask.StartAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

I'm using dotnet6. Please Help. And sorry for all the grammatical errors.
Thank you.

Comment: What unexpected behavior you are noticing?

Comment: Hello @Chetan , If take a look at the `Increase` method from the `PaymentIncrease` class, Here I'm trying to increase student payment and update the data. Also tying add a new record to the `Dues` table.  None of them are happening. Thank you.

Comment: You have an empty catch block... so even if there is an exception happening in the code you never know... you will see nothing is happening with no errors... so you need to log the exception Message in the catch block to know if there is any exception and what is the exception.

Comment: It is even better to have try...catch block in Increase Method. and log exception in that catch block.

Comment: Sorry, @Chetan I'm just a beginner in this field. Can help me with how can I do this, please?

Comment: `catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);}`

Comment: You need to learn how to use logging frameworks in your applications. The logging frameworks such as Log4net, NLog, Serilog etc. There are plenty of resources available on internet which can teach you how to use them to log messages and errors to console or files etc.